# Pinging an IP address responds with different IP

Tags: ip, ping

When I try to ping the IP address `10.10.208.57` I have no response since nothing exist in the network with that IP address.

However if I try to ping `10.10.208.`**0**`57` instead another IP address responds:

```
root@everest:/root# ping 10.10.208.057
PING 10.10.208.057 (10.10.208.47) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.208.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=0.732 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.208.47: icmp_seq=2 ttl=253 time=0.695 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.208.47: icmp_seq=3 ttl=253 time=0.659 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.208.47: icmp_seq=4 ttl=253 time=0.705 ms
```

Considering that `10.10.208.47` is a Lexmark E120n printer what could be the origin of this strange problem?

Comment: Bump, look at the answer in this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That behavior is actually due to a normal feature of ping and has no relation to your actual hardware.

Indeed, prefixing the IP address (or part of it) with a leading zero will cause the number to be interpreted as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

So `057` means `57` in base 8 which is 47. Thus ping will send the [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) query to the machine located at address `10.10.208.47` and therefore get an answer from it.

Note that you can also ping adresses in hexadecimal, by using the 0x prefix instead of just 0.

Edit : As many comments suggest, this feature is actually not specific to `ping` and can be found in many CLI softwares manipulating IP addresses.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you! My heart stopped for a bunch of minutes :-)

Comment: Not just ping. Lots of things do that.

Comment: Bash treats all "integers" like that http://askubuntu.com/questions/621500/why-does-bash-thinks-that-010-is-8

Answer (score 15):

Ping, like many other unix programs, use the C libraries on your unix system for name resolution. One of the functions used is `inet_aton`.

The man page for `inet_aton` says:

> All numbers supplied as ``parts'' in a `.' notation may be decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, as specified in the C language (i.e., a leading 0x or 0X implies hexadecimal; otherwise, a leading 0 implies octal; otherwise, the number is interpreted as decimal).

So when you're using a leading  zero, the number is interpreted as a octal. Thus, 57 = 047 = 0x39.

Comment: I noticed even Windows behaves the same. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: @PsyStyle You're welcome! It's a standard notation for numbers, across a wide spectrum of operating systems and programming languages.

Comment: "So when you're using a leading zero, the number is interpreted as a decimal.". I think this is a typo, you meant interpreted as octal right?

Comment: Thanks @Cruncher. I blame too high a concentration of blood in my caffeine stream.